# Are usb 2.0 limitations below 150 mbps for hard drive file share

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I'm planning on having a Raspberry Pi in my basement with a copuple of usb 3.0 hard drives so it would work kinda like a NAS. The USB drive can only do about 150 mbps which is fine but I'm looking at the Raspberry Pi 1 model B+ which only has USB 2.0 and I was wondering wether that would significantly slow down the hard drives?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing Megabyte/s and Megabit/s?

Comment: I would be more worried about the power required to turn on the multiple HDDs connected to an RPI. There are hundreds of articles on how to properly turn an RPI into a NAS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are mixing up megabyte and megabit.

A hard drive can probably manage (at peak) 150 megabytes per second while USB2 can manage 480 megabits per second, which is roughly 40 megabytes per second. Your USB2 is definitely going to be the limit here.

More realistically though the Wi-Fi or Ethernet you connect to is going to be the actual limit at I believe the RPi 1 had 100 Mbps Ethernet and if you use a USB Wi-Fi dongle then that will also be sharing bandwidth with the hard drive.

Comment: RPi 1's Ethernet is attached through USB, so it will be sharing bandwidth either way.